# not enough arguments to satisfy format string

Tags: awk

What is wrong with this, please?

```
awk '{printf "%10.5f  %6.4f  %6.4f  %6.4f  %6.4f R\n, $1, $4, $5, $7, $8"}' R.dat > R0
```

It gives the error: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
There are five % to format 5 $columns.

Comment: You have a good question and you have posted your attempt at a solution (good job!), but in the future, you need to try and describe the problem with more particularity. For example it would be nice to see several lines of `R.dat` showing the exact input you are using as well as the command output (at least the first few lines) along with your expected output. This would allow everyone to confirm the issue you are having and be confident that the answer given would address that problem. Not a criticism, just a bit of helpful advice for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it like following manner. Where we need to enclose all formatting parameters inside `"...."` and then other section(after `,`) we need to put whatever field values/variables etc are the ones which we want to print in current line.

```
awk '{printf "%10.5f  %6.4f  %6.4f  %6.4f  %6.4f R\n", $1, $4, $5, $7, $8}' R.dat > R0
```

OR to make it more clear use like:

```
awk '{printf("%10.5f  %6.4f  %6.4f  %6.4f  %6.4f R\n", $1, $4, $5, $7, $8)}' R.dat > R0
```